# How do i make my theme button changer affect all pages on my site not just the homepage?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

Basically I have a Button for changing the theme/colour of the website however it only works on the homepage it does not affect any other pages. How do i fix this?

JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        $("div").css("background", "grey");
        return false;
    });
});
```

HTML code:

```
<button> Change Theme</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can handle this situation from both ends.

front end - by using js cookie to store the theme of color in a cookie, and retrive it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        document.cookie = "theme=grey";
        return false;
    });
});


let themeColor = document.cookie;
```

or

```
var getCookie = (key) => {
    a = [];
    x = document.cookie.split('; ');
    for (var i = x.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        b = x[i].split('=');
        a[b[0]] = b[1];
    };
    return (key) ? a[key] : a;
};

function setCookie (name, value) {
    document.cookie = name + '=' + value;
    return getCookie();
}

setCookie('theme', 'grey');
let themeColor = getCookie('theme');
```

back end - by storing the theme color on your preference table and fetch it.

Comment: [visit here](https://nikhiltiwari005.github.io/JavaScriptWebPage/basic.html) check out the color picker and also go through the source code or chrome dev tool

Answer (score 0):

Navigating to a new page will reload the script and styles from their files, preventing the DOM changes you have made from your function from appearing in the new page.
You could circumvent this by using local or session storage. Have your above function do something like this:

```
$('button').click(function () {
  localStorage.setItem('isGreyTheme', true)
}
```

And then you can have code run inside of your document ready like so:

```
const isGrey = localStorage.getItem('isGreyTheme')
if (isGrey) {
  $('div').css('background', 'grey');
} else {
   // handle other cases
}
```

Local storage is the simplest way to persist data across pages. You could also use session storage, depending on your needs. Use session storage if you do not want this theme to persist if the window is closed, and use local storage if you want the theme to persist unless explicitly changed.

Comment: What other cases could i handle because i am new to JavaScript so im not to sure what i should put there.

Comment: In your implementation as, nothing is necessary to put there. But you could put a wide variety of things in there to enhance your UX. Some thoughts off the top of my head are: you could emphasize the button somehow (outline) to indicate to the user they have the option to change the theme. You could add additional conditions to account for a variety of themes. Hope that helps.